# Spring Integration Message History

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have setup `@EnableMessageHistory`

I have created custom transformers like this

```
public class FileMoveTransformer implements GenericTransformer<CustomerPojo, CustomerPojo> {
    private boolean renameFile;
    private String toLocation;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileMoveTransformer.class);


    public FileMoveTransformer(String toLocation, final boolean renameFile) {
        this.toLocation = toLocation;
        this.renameFile = renameFile;
    }


    @Override
    public CustomerPojo transform(CustomerPojo input) {

    return input;

    }

}
```

When I look at the Message history its showing like this

[image]

How do I change the "name" attribute to my own transformer as above will make not sense to print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MessageHistory` makes it based on the bean name:

```
private static Properties extractMetadata(NamedComponent component) {
    Entry entry = new Entry();
    String name = component.getComponentName();
    String type = component.getComponentType();
    if (name != null && !name.startsWith("org.springframework.integration")) {
        entry.setName(name);
        if (type != null) {
            entry.setType(type);
        }
    }
    if (!entry.isEmpty()) {
        entry.setTimestamp(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
    return entry;
}
```

Since you don't provide an explicit `id` for the endpoint which uses your `FileMoveTransformer`, you get that generated bean name based on the endpoint `ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean` class.

Since you don't show how you use this `FileMoveTransformer`, I only can abuse guessing that it is about an `IntegrationFlow` and you have something like this:

```
.transform(new FileMoveTransformer())
```

So, consider to add an `id` there like:

```
.transform(new FileMoveTransformer(), e -> e.id("fileMoveTransformer"))
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-endpoints

Otherwise, please, share how you use it and we will let you know what need to be changed to bring your own custom id for the component and make your message history much readable.

Comment: Thanks.Exactly I was looking for.